# Which Characters Do I Need to Escape in this SQL Command?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am replacing some URLs in a MySQL database.  Im worried that I need to escape some characters in the first url in the update command.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace( post_content, 'http://www.website.com/soft/www/test/ck.php?oaparams…o__cb=658ac30cf5__oadest=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.site.com/page.html', 'http://www.newsite.com' ) ;
```

Should this work as is, or do I need to escape the `_`'s and `%`'s?

Comment: What happened when you did it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your code works well.  If it's not working, check the data in your table and see how it's stored.

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3edb/1).

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks and thanks for letting me know about SQL Fiddle.  Great tool.